# NodeJS - Disable JSONP on specific routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm using Express. How do I disable `JSONP` for specific routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [`res.json()`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/2.5.11/lib/response.js#L129), it appears there's no explicit setting to disable JSONP per-route – it only checks the global app setting `jsonp callback`.

You could simply clear the value of `req.query.callback` before calling `res.json()` in any route you don't want to work via JSONP.  As a middleware function:

```
function noJSONP(req, res, next) {
    delete req.query.callback;
    next();
}
```

Now you can just do this:

```
app.get('/something/sensitive', noJSONP, function(req, res) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I agree.  Since you have to globally *enable* JSONP and then turn it off route-by-route, this opens the door to accidentally having private routes accessible cross-origin.  A more security conscious way would be to leave JSONP globally disabled and then be able to selectively enable JSONP for specific routes.  I've [filed this as an issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1240).

Comment: TJ likes to keep things minimalistic. I hope they merge this though, tons of middlewares just doesn't feel right. See this similar issue which was closed https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1239